# Fatal error EE::clean() - Discussion Forum

Tags: ee2, forum, discussion

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE::clean() in /system/expressionengine/modules/forum/mod.forum_core.php on line 6427

```
$temp['answer'] = ee('Security/XSS')->clean($val);
```

Any pointers?

Using:
Discussion Forum v3.1.22
EE v2.11.9

Answer (score 1):

Checked the documentation and found that the correct code is

```
$temp['answer'] = ee('Security/XSS')->security->xss_clean($val);
```

Ref: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/guidelines/security.html